# Dolby equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, sound, software-recommendation

I got a chance to try Dolby audio from Windows 10 store. Just wondering whether Ubuntu (16.04) has an alternative.

Comment: have a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound

Answer (score 21):

I've googled out a very good advice on forums that helps me to achieve a Dolby-like sound on my Kubuntu 19.04 with Lenovo G780.

The effect is achieved by EasyEffects (previously known as PulseEffects)

Install EasyEffects:

- Update your packages and repositories using `sudo apt update`
- Most up-to-date Linux distributions have an easyeffects package that can be installed with the distribution package manager. For Ubuntu 22.10 and later install EasyEffects with:

  ```
  sudo apt install easyeffects
  ```

  For earlier versions of Ubuntu there is an EasyEffects flatpak package at FlatHub.
- Restart the user session or reboot after this, because PulseAudio will be upgraded, and it may cause problems if you don't restart.
- Run EasyEffects and close it. It'll create all settings directoriess on the first launch. They are required for next step.

Install EasyEffects [**presets**](https://github.com/JackHack96/EasyEffects-Presets) using:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JackHack96/PulseEffects-Presets/master/install.sh)"
```

Launch EasyEffects again. Click the effects session. Click on *Add Effect*, Select *Convolver*. Now convolver will be added. Click on *Impulses* on the right, You'll see a list of presets. Select:

> Dolby ATMOS ((128K MP3)) 1.Default.irs

That's it. You can toggle Convolver in PulseEffects on and off while playing music to compare results. You may play with other presets as well.

The app can be minimized to the tray on GTK-enabled desktops with an additional application: https://github.com/boomshop/pulseffectstray

Enable *Launch service at system startup* autostart in app Preferences to start it without GUI the next time.

Comment: Now much better, thanks :) works on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Great answer. Should be accepted.

Comment: It does sound different on a thinkpad p53, Ubuntu 20

Comment: I got 1&2 done. On 3 I got a bunch of warnings when running `pulseeffects` in the terminal, but it did open. I closed it and ran `sudo apt install flatpak`, which installed. But on step 4, even though I followed the link, I'm not seeing any instructions on how to use flatpak to install the next bit of software? It just kinda says at the bottom, "If you used flatpak..."

Can anyone fill in this missing step for me?

Comment: @PinkieB Instructions are here: https://github.com/JackHack96/EasyEffects-Presets#installation
your need to execute `bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JackHack96/PulseEffects-Presets/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 6):

```
Windows 10 PC Support Notice:
This application is designed specifically for PC Manufacturers and comes
pre-installed on licensed devices. It will not function properly on
unlicensed devices.
```

*Dolby Audio* is a proprietary technology, and is something featured with specific hardware in a system. The only way to enable Dolby features on such hardware is with proprietary drivers, which as of yet, do not appear to have been released for Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the Dolby clarification, Dobey.